Trying to link my Javascript file to my HTML file
main folder and html src, inside js folder
I'm trying to link my js file that is in a folder to my html file, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm creating a dropdown menu and using js to open the dropdown. The console log shows no errors, but none of the script is coming through. It works when I put the script into the html, but it needs to be in a separate file in a folder because it's part of the instructions for the assignment. The file I'm linking to is the dropdown-menu file at the bottom. Let me know if I can make anything clearer.
I've tried putting the src in the header, in the body tag at the end, and just outside of the end of the body tag. I've also tried "js/dropdown-menu.js", "/js/dropdown-menu.js", "../js/dropdown-menu.js", but it didn't make a difference either.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Can you check in browser console if you are getting 404 for not including the js file.

Nope no error in the console unfortunately.

Maybe what is not working is your content of the .js file and not the reference to the file itself. What you can do for this is add a function so that clicking a button triggers an alert. This will help you know if it is a linking problem with the .js file or not.
I share with you the example of the code that you must add in your dropdown-menu.js file and in your HTML:
<!-- HTML file -->
<button id="btn" >click me</button>

// JS file
button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('button clicked');
});

If this code works then the error is inside dropdown-menu.js, maybe you should share it so I can review it too.

I don't think it is a problem with the code, as it works when I put it directly into the HTML, but if it would help I could post the code. I'm brand new to stack, would it be best to paste the code into a comment box, or is there a better way? Thanks!

You can share it in a Github gist

Ok thanks, let me know if you can't view it  https://gist.github.com/lschmi/0c0ffd8cba8eed2d8a080ac616e0b680

The error was in the code and not in the link with the .js file. I left you the code reviews in the Gist.

You were right, that was it thank you!!

You may use the script html tag with a fitting relative path.

Thanks for the reply! Would you be able to give me an example of what you mean?


Oh gotchya, sorry my main post was confusing I've already tried   
